# JQuery run until new page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using jquery to run code *once* my page has loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    \\ stuff
};
```

How do you write jquery to run only if the page has already loaded and is redirecting, but the new website has *not* loaded yet? Any suggestions?

Comment: Just don't use `$(window).load(function(){ };`. Anything you put in `<script></script>` tags will be executed immediately wherever you put it. So you can put `<script>alert('hello');</script>` right inside your `<head></head>` tags and it will show an alert before it starts rendering the page.

Comment: I'm trying to run some functions after the page has loaded and while my page is trying to loading a new one. Adding to the script only runs until the initial load is complete

Comment: window.onload = function(){  } or $(document).ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can begin executing code immediately:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    runSomeCode();
</script>
```

If you want it to *stop* running at a given event, then presumably what you have is some asynchronous operation which will repeat while the page loads.  Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(someFunction, someTimeout);
</script>
```

You can stop the operation when the event occurs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var operation = setInterval(someFunction, someTimeout);

    $(window).load(function(){
        clearInterval(operation);
    };
</script>
```

However the operation is defined or constructed, it would *have* to be asynchronous in order for the page to continue to load.  And it would *have* to be a loop in order for it to be "stopped".  (Or at the very least some sequence of operations which checks a condition before executing each step.)

So basically you would start the operation based on some flag (in the above case the `operation` variable, but in other structures perhaps just a simple boolean value), check for the flag within the operation's loop, and cancel the flag in the event handler.